# Is блин a euphemism for блядь?

Tags: одним-словом

Was блин's development independent of блядь? Does anybody have something to say to whether it is a euphemism of блядь this statement? (or against it).

Answer (score 3):

Yes, "блин" is one of several an euphemism of блядь.
More examples: млин, плин, млять, плять, бляха-муха, ...

Comment: and what's wrong with блядь? I've always thought those cute ways of "not swearing" are lame, in Russian and in English. Fuck and bitch and slut, etc are perfectly fine words if used in context.

Comment: Nothing wrong with блядь. I think in Russian, "ебать, сука, блядь" much heavier than 'fuck, bitch, slut' in English, so I can't imagine a child saying 'блядь' without punishment, but speaking the word 'блин' acceptable.

Comment: @VCH250: words like "frigging" and "gosh darn" exist in every language, lame though it may be.

Comment: True, but lame)

Answer (score 2):

Also, ussually блядь means a whore, but блять is interjection and true swearing. And you can change "блять" not only by "блин", but by "сука" too.

Answer (score 1):

`Блин` is only a filler word and is a euphemism only in that position, you can't use it as a noun. And is almost acceptable. Russian linguist [Maxim Krongauz mentions](http://www.e-reading.club/chapter.php/101730/45/Krongauz_-_Russkiii_yazyk_na_grani_nervnogo_sryva.html) it being used on stage at award ceremonies.

> В начале книги я назвал актера Евгения Миронова, использовавшего *блин* в благодарственном слове при вручении ему премии. Прошло несколько лет, и уже писатель Дмитрий Быков, вручая ту же премию, зачитывает поэтическое послание, в котором есть такие строки: «Вот вы сидите – номинанты, блин, – инфанты, дебютанты, неофиты, – а через пять минут из вас один пойдет под эти хищные софиты».

Older generation (50 and older) hear it as rude and often told us off and demanded "Без блинов!" Krongauz writes that he (born in 1950s) strongly dislikes it, meanwhile his father strongly opposed to the word `фиг` which was also an euphemism to a strong obscenity. But nowadays its byproducts (`фиг вам`, `фиговина`) are 99% inoffencive, although definitely not acceptable in high style.

Comment: To what фиг was an euphemism?

Comment: @Anixx I found this quote: "словарь Флегона определяет это слово, как эвфемизм слова из трех букв, в котором первая буква, как в слове "художник", вторая, - как в слове "удочка", а с третьей буквы ни одно слово в современном русском языке (за исключением словечек иноязычных) не начинается."

Comment: С какой стати? Фига - это обозначение конкретного жеста, означающего отказ. Почему слово "фиг" не может обозначать именно этот жест? Сам же жест больше похож на сосок женской груди. Так что, более вероятно, что "фига" - эвфеминизм для женской сиськи, учитывая её схожесть с фиговым фруктом (инжиром). Сиськи и персями называли по схожести с персиком.

Comment: @Anixx  По библейскому преданию Ева, познавшая после грехопадения стыд, опоясалась, чтобы прикрыть свою наготу, листьями смоковницы (фигового дерева). Позже (с XVI по XVIII в.) в скульптуре и живописи фиговый листок стал изображаться на месте половых органов обнажённых фигур. Далее метонимия фиг -> место, которое он прикрывает.

Comment: @Anixx вы вопрос задаёте или свой тезис? Я не думаю, что Кронгауз врёт и придумывает. НЯП, эвфемизм потребовался в литературе, и взяли его от названия жеста. И он похож не на сосок груди, а на гениталии, и во всём мире именно это и значит (и не отказ) - попробуйте итальянцам или испанцам показать такое - много нового узнаете. :)

Answer (score 1):

### Usage

Usage of "*Блин!*" is close to English "*Damn!*", "*Shit!*" or "*Crap!*"

Literally this word means "[a Russian pancake](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%8B)", but obviously, it replaces a hard swear word "Блядь" in mentioned meanings (*"Damn!", ...*) thanks to the same initial letters "**бл**"

### Examples

- Damn! I broke my nail! - Блин! Я сломала ноготь!
- Hey! You will not get you money today... - Дарова! Ты не получишь свои деньги сегодня...
- Oh crap... - Вот блин...